# Updating my variables in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to update my variable startPreyPopulationSize and startPredatorPopulation size everytime it iterates but I'm not sure how to go about that since the bottom for loop affects the top one right?

```
    //Equation to find out prey population size.
    for(double rate = 0; rate <= numberOfPeriods; rate++) {

        double partOne = startPreyPopulationSize / rate * (1 + RATE_A_BIRTH - RATE_B_PREDATION * (startPredatorPopulationSize / rate));
        double updatedPreyPopulation = startPreyPopulationSize / (rate + 1);
        updatedPreyPopulation = partOne;
        System.out.printf("Period %5.0f: Prey Population %.2f; \n", rate, updatedPreyPopulation);

    }


    //Equation to find out predator population size.
    for(double rate2 = 0; rate2 <= numberOfPeriods; rate2++) {
        double partTwoEquation = startPredatorPopulationSize / rate2 * (1 - RATE_C_DEATHS + RATE_D_INCREASE * (startPreyPopulationSize / rate2));
        double updatedPredatorPopulation = startPredatorPopulationSize / (rate2 + 1);
        updatedPredatorPopulation = partTwoEquation;
        System.out.printf("Period %5.0f: Predator Population %.2f; \n", rate2, updatedPredatorPopulation);
    }
```

UPDATED CODE I'm basing my formula off of this if it helps http://i.imgur.com/rUQ774q.jpg I know my formula is off somehow.

```
    //Equation to find out prey population size.
    for(double rate = 0; rate < numberOfPeriods; rate++) {

        partOne = startPreyPopulationSize / rate * (1 + RATE_A_BIRTH - RATE_B_PREDATION * (startPredatorPopulationSize / rate));
        currentPreyPopulationSize = startPreyPopulationSize / (rate + 1);
        currentPreyPopulationSize = partOne;
        System.out.printf("Period %5.0f: Prey Population %.2f; \n", rate, currentPreyPopulationSize);

        partTwoEquation = startPredatorPopulationSize / rate * (1 - RATE_C_DEATHS + RATE_D_INCREASE * (startPreyPopulationSize / rate));
        currentPredatorPopulationSize = startPredatorPopulationSize / (rate + 1);
        currentPredatorPopulationSize = partTwoEquation;
        System.out.printf("Period %5.0f: Predator Population %.2f; \n", rate, currentPredatorPopulationSize);


        startPreyPopulationSize = currentPreyPopulationSize;
        startPredatorPopulationSize = currentPredatorPopulationSize;
    }
```

Comment: Use 1 for loop only here and update both in the same loop.

Comment: Without looking at your code, why would the bottom loop affect the top one?

Comment: And your calculations are **way** off. You need to get the initialization code **outside** of the for loops. Otherwise you re-initialize the populations with each iteration of the loop, and so the populations won't change.

Comment: I'm getting infinity values when I run this I'm really confused.

Comment: @ErickVillalpando, Do you have output for the sample input stated in http://i.imgur.com/rUQ774q.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Well your code for equations you provided is wrong.

1) In equation you have no division by `rate`, so it should look like

```
double currentPreyPopulationSize = startPreyPopulationSize * (1 + RATE_A_BIRTH - RATE_B_PREDATION * (startPredatorPopulationSize));
```

2) Also this division causing the `-Infinity`, because `rate` is `0` for the first iteration.

Comment: So what would I be using the subscript "n" for? It's the rate I know that but would it be used inside my for loop?

Comment: @Erick Villalpando it's not a division, it's index - number of preys and predators for the n-th and (n+1)-th period. You need it to output the period number and do calculations desired number of times (you get it from user input). Since this you should change ``numberOfPeriods`` and ``rate`` to ``int``.